# How to starting QFileDialog in TreeView C++ Qt4

Tags: c++, c, qt

I making graphic user interface application with qt c++.
I'm opening the system directory with `QFileDialog`.

The code follows, I clicked pushbutton opening window QFileDialog.

```
QString dirname=qfileDialog::getExistingdirectory(
                    this,
                    QDir::homePath());
```

I don't want that. Started first program, I want to show `qfiledialog` in treeview. How to start `QFileDialog` in treeview?

Comment: What do you mean by "treeview"? a filedialog in qt only has detail and listview as modes. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#ViewMode-enum

Comment: My intention is that the QFileDialog window opens automatically when the program starts, and the GUI looks where I want it to be. @Hayt

Comment: How do I fix the Qfiledialog window in the gui @Hayt

Comment: A "dialog" is by definition it's own window. If you want to put it into a widget from your own GUI you have to work with a `QTreeView` and the filesystem model. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html

Comment: Maybe qMdiAreah help you